# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update - updating row count?

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-nhibernate

When adding a new row in a table right after deleting one, I'm getting such an error:
"Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: %x; expected: %(x+1)", where x - is a number of rows after deleting and before inserting.

Code for deleting:

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            session.Delete((Word)row.DataBoundItem);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Code for adding:

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        language.AddWord(word);
        session.SaveOrUpdate(language);
        transaction.Commit();
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public WordMapping()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    Map(x => x.Word1);
    Map(x => x.Word2);
        Map(x => x.Count);
        References(x => x.Language)
            .Not.LazyLoad();
}
```

SQL code, that is written to debug:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Word] (Word1, Word2, Count, Language_id) 
    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); 
    select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    @p0 = 't2' [Type: String (4000)], 
    @p1 = 't2' [Type: String (4000)], 
    @p2 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0)], 
    @p3 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Can you give me a hint what to do? Maybe I should somehow update the number of rows?